# Trying to generate random number between a range based on an input, returns number outside range

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to generate a random number between a range based on a user input, the problem is that the program seems to store a number outside of the specified range when I run it. In the example below, I input `8` and 'puts ex_val' returns `247.5`. `8` shouldn't be giving me anything higher than `170.001`, where am I going wrong here?

```
class Example

  print "Input number between 1-12: "
  example_range = gets.chomp

  if example_range = 11 || 12
    ex_val = rand(212.502..255)
  elsif example_range = 9 || 10
    ex_val = rand(170.002..212.501)
  elsif example_range = 7 || 8
    ex_val = rand(127.5..170.001)
  elsif example_range = 5 || 6
    ex_val = rand(84.999..127.499)
  elsif example_range = 3 || 4
    ex_val = rand(42.499..84.998)
  elsif example_range = 1 || 2
    ex_val = rand(0..42.498)
  end

  puts ex_val.round(1)

end
```

I tried using 'when' instead of if statements like so:

```
case example_range    
when 11, 12
  ex_val = rand(212.502..255)
...
end
```

but that always seemed to just return the original input.

Comment: so, what's output? btw, do you really need class for this? -))

Comment: I probably don't, it's just one of the many things I've tried while troubleshooting this. This is one of 3 similar parts, I'm just posting it for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if example_range = 11 || 12`

is an assigning, resulting in `example_range` variable assigned with value `11`.
Since this condition is *truthy* your program does not go further and returns

```
rand(212.502..255)
```

Double equal sign (`==`) is used for comparison.

In your case you want to use something like

```
if [11, 12].include?(example_range)
```

P.S.

```
example_range = gets.chomp
```

returns a String object, not Integer - you need to convert the `example_range` (using `to_i`) before comparing with integers.

Comment: And, of course, `example_range == 11 || example_range == 12`!

Comment: Okay I used Ken Y-N's correction as well as this, I'm getting "undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" now.

Comment: The to_i fixed it!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't work for two reasons:

- First `=` is an assignment not an comparison like Andrey Deineko already explained.
- Second `gets.chomp` returns a string not an integer. Since you try to compare the user's input against integers non of the condions can be true.

Furthermore I would like to suggest a refactoring of the `if ..elsif` blocks to a hash lookup. IMO this makes it easier to read, to understand and to maintain:

```
fraction = (255/6.to_f)
ranges = {
   '1' => ((fraction * 0)...(fraction * 1)),
   '2' => ((fraction * 0)...(fraction * 1)),
   '3' => ((fraction * 1)...(fraction * 2)),
   '4' => ((fraction * 1)...(fraction * 2)),
   '5' => ((fraction * 2)...(fraction * 3)),
   '6' => ((fraction * 2)...(fraction * 3)), 
   '7' => ((fraction * 3)...(fraction * 4)),
   '8' => ((fraction * 3)...(fraction * 4)),
   '9' => ((fraction * 4)...(fraction * 5)),
  '10' => ((fraction * 4)...(fraction * 5)),
  '11' => ((fraction * 5)..(fraction * 6)),
  '12' => ((fraction * 5)..(fraction * 6))
}

print 'Input number between 1-12: '
range = gets.chomp

puts rand(ranges[range]).round(1)
```